# How to set executor number in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In spark, we can set executor number.

In mapreduce, how to set the executor number? Not set map or reduce task num, but set executor num.

I know how to set vcores and mem each map or reduce task use.
But there are so many map tasks, and I don't want my mr job use too much resource.

Answer (score 0):

The number of `mappers` depends on the number of `splits` for your input data, which depends on `InputFormat`, that said user can give hint about number of `mappers` via `mapreduce.job.maps`, but `InputFormat` may choose to ignore it tho. Number of reducers is configureable via `mapreduce.job.reduces`.

Comment: thanks, what i want to know is not how to set map or reduce task num, but how to set executor num.

Comment: @HoganFan there is not such thing like executor num in MR. There are NodeManagers (part of YARN cluster) - which execute tasks, number of NM and their settings is cluster not job configuration.